# Debug Assertion Failed caused by CreateDC() function

Tags: c++, printing, mfc, windows-ce

I have a problem with Debug Assertion Failed (picture) [Debug Assertion Failed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S7VG2.jpg)
This problem occur when I push "Print" button on dialog box a second time. (on first time work well)
Dialog Box:
[Dialog Box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/On259.png)

After debugging code I guess it is caused when I create DC second time.
But I can explain why, because ealier I delete DC by DeleteDC() function.
Below I put snippets of code when I initialize DC and delete DC.

```
    BOOL Druk::StartPrint()
{
    //Configuration();
    hDC.CreateDC(DriverName, DeviceName, OutputName, NULL);
    StartDoc(hDC, NULL);
    //StartPage(hDC);
    return TRUE;
}
```

BOOL Druk::ZakonczDruk()

```
{
    EndDoc(hDC);
    //EndPage(hDC);
    DeleteDC(hDC);
    return TRUE;
}
```

Comment: Don't post images of text, but add them verbatim and (code) formatted to your quesiton please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are using MFC's `CDC` class, evidenced by

```
hDC.CreateDC(DriverName, DeviceName, OutputName, NULL);
```

For symmetry sake, delete it also by that class' method: [CDC::DeleteDC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/cdc-class?view=vs-2019#deletedc)

```
hDC.DeleteDC();
```